# scala change log4j.property output folder based on environment

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a scala project with a log4j.properties file. The output folder in my local is different from the output folder in dev, QA, prod. Is there a way to update the location of this file when doing an SBT build.

Long back I had used ant, where we had a build.properties file that will substitute values in properties file based on values in build.properties file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) when your application loads, based on the environment export the variable,

```
//if dev
System.setProperty("logger_file_name", "my-log-name-for-env-dev");
// so on
```

2) Or use JVM option,

```
java -Dlogger_file_name=my-log-name-for-env-dev  your.package.MainApplication
```

Then in your `src/main/log4j.properties`, refer to the system variable

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${logger_file_name}.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**3) the third way which I like better for obvious reasons,**

maintain a map of `environment to log file name` or simply maintain a way to know which environment you are in, and then while application is loading, set the proper log4j config.

//for log4j

```
val environment = System.getProperty("application.environment");    
org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure("src/main/resources/log4j-"+environment+".properties")
```

//for log4j2

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator

val environment = System.getProperty("application.environment");

Configurator.initialize(null, "src/main/resources/log4j2-"+environment+".properties"));
```

And, you will have to have something as below structure

```
src/main/resources/
    log4j2-dev.properties
    log4j2-e2e.properties
    log4j2-uat.properties
    log4j2-prod.properties
```

Comment: I like the 3rd option but where is the ConfigurationSource and Configurator??

Comment: @user373201 I initialliy added log4j2 one, which is different than in log4j. use `PropertyConfigurator` for log4j 1.x. answer is updated

Comment: The way I do is third one, where I have environment variable `APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT=prod` which is done with `export APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT=prod` in my `/etc/profile`